# Is it better to walk or run when there is rain?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, vectors

When I was coming from school to my house, there was heavy rain. Then one of my friends said  "Don't simply walk, run fast". Then the question came to my mind: how should I go so as to avoid wetting: walk or run?

Comment: Did you've raincoat???

Comment: Is this a joke..??

Comment: Depends on my mood. Sometimes I like to walk and sometimes I run. Mostly I walk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you run when under rain?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19499/)

Comment: My question was how should I avoid rain??

Comment: Please make the effort to [search this site for duplicates](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=walk+run+rain) before posting a new question.

Comment: @John Rennie: Probably he is eating Nestle Maggie! Surely this is horrendous; within two min, I saw questions that were asked earlier. Are they lazy? I am surely asking a question on meta to discuss this matter.

Comment: I am a newbie to this site, and the world of physics though i always find time to search through old posts before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the rain is pretty consistent in the interim you have to go between two points. Your front side absorbs most of the water as you move along the path. Every moment you're moving, your shirt gets some water in it. The water density of the environment is pretty consistent now, so if you move faster, you trace out a larger volume differential in that moment and get hit with proportionally more water. In the end, you're about as wet as you would be if you had walked.

On the other hand, your hair would be dryer if you ran probably. Don't slip and hurt yourself though.